# Can I connect the iOS and the windows with Bluetooth low energy?

Tags: ios, wpf, windows, bluetooth, btle

### I have a project which need to connect the windows PC and iOS device with bluetooth.

1. As I get, in the iOS platform, I can use the CoreBluetooth and the
   iOS device act as the peripheral device. This won't be a question.
2. However, at the windows platform, I would like to using the WPF to
   implement the software. But I can't find the api and something else
   that can be used.

So, is there any possible to implement this?
Thanks, very much.

Comment: what software and api are you implementing? I'm not really sure what the question is...

Comment: A iOS app which control the PPT in the windows PC. I have implemented it by LAN, but it also need to implement by bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj159880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Windows 8 supports BLE.  You should be able to do this with no problem.  I'm guessing you will design your own GATT based protocol.  [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95) is a sample from Microsoft.